# efficient way to attach multiple handler to single logger

Tags: python, logging

I've multiple handler and I want to attach it to single handler. Is there any efficient way to do this.

```
logger = logging.getLogger('logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

summary = logging.FileHandler(filename='text_logger.txt', mode='w')
summary.setLevel(logging.INFO)

overview = logging.FileHandler(filename='overview.log', mode='w')

logger.addHandler(console_handler)
logger.addHandler(summary)
logger.addHandler(overview)
```

I've to use `addHandler` multiple times. Is there any better way to do this, something like providing list. I quickly went through doc but didn't find it. I might have missed something.

I am thinking defining `dict` is an option. But suggestion.

Comment: There is not. Btw, I add my handlers after creating them - it makes changes more intuitive as all code relating to that handler next to it. I actually have conditional handler creation (e.g. will use stdout handler only if -v/--verbose flag is present) thanks to that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `addHandler()` does is appending the handler to a list in the logger. So if you want to add multiple handlers with a single expression you can do this by extending the list directly:
`logger.handlers.extend([console_handler, summary, overview])`

Be aware that `addHandler()` explicitly is thread safe, so by bypassing that you are losing this protection.